# Write to BQ one field of the rows of a PColl - Need the entire row for table selection

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have a problem:

My Pcoll is made of rows with this format

{'word':'string','table':'string'}

I want to write into BigQuery only the words, however I need the table field to be able to select the right table in BigQuery.

This is how my pipeline looks:

```
tobq = (input
        | 'write names to BigQuery '>> beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery(
          table=compute_table_name, schema=compute_schema,
          insert_retry_strategy='RETRY_ON_TRANSIENT_ERROR',
          create_disposition=beam.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
          write_disposition=beam.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
       )
```

The function compute_table_name accesses an element and returns the table field. Is there a way to write into BQ just the words while still having this table selection mechanism based on rows?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normally the best approach with a situation like this in BigQuery is to use the `ignoreUnknownValues` parameter in [`ExternalDataConfiguration`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#externaldataconfiguration). Unfortunately Apache Beam doesn't yet support enabling this parameter while writing to BigQuery, so we must find a workaround, as follows:

### Pass a Mapping of IDs to Tables as a `table_side_input`

This solution only works if identical `word` values are guaranteed to map to the same table each time, or there is some kind of unique identifier for your elements. This method is a bit more involved than Solution 1, but it relies only on the Beam model instead of having to touch the BigQuery API.

The solution involves making use of [`table_side_input`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.28.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html#table-references) to dynamically pick which table to place an element even if the element is missing the `table` field. The basic idea is to create a dict of ID:table (where ID is either the unique ID, or just the `word` field). Creating this dict can be done with [`CombineGlobally`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#combine) by combining all elements into a single dict.

Meanwhile, you use a transform to drop the `table` field from your elements before the `WriteToBigQuery` transform. Then you pass the dict into the `table_side_input` parameter of `WriteToBigQuery`, and write a callable `table` parameter that checks with the dict to figure out which table to use, instead of the `table` field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Regarding solution 1, it seems that ignoreUnknownValues is not supported for streaming pipelines: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/9a3ba93d4313de9280fa5edf708e5aeb4efbb70e/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_tools.py#L476

Regarding solution 2, unfortunately there are many key fields which are named the same in every table, however, I could write a function which applies some logic to the content of the fields (ex checks if one field is present) and returns the right table.

Comment: I guess something we could add as a feature is a 'mapping function' that allows you to change the rows right before they're submitted to BQ - or support ignoreUnknownValues for streaming. For now, I think the option you consider could work (figure out the table by record share rather tan from a field...)

Comment: I adjusted my answer to remove the suggestion for setting `ignoreUnknownValues` (with a short note to indicate that this approach would be preferable once there's support for it)